Pyramid Auth classes in Pyramid 2.x
I’m working on upgrading a project from Pyramid 1.4 to 2.x, and I’ve hit a roadblock with the deprecation of AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy and ACLAuthorizationPolicy. These were the backbone of my authentication and authorization system, and I’m unsure how to transition to the new implementation in Pyramid 2.x.
I would appreciate any guidance or examples on how to replace these deprecated classes with the recommended approach in Pyramid 2.x. Below is a snippet of my current setup:
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from pyramid.config import Configurator


def main(settings):
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
        "somesecret123", cookie_name="session-id", wild_domain=True, hashalg="sha512"
    )
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()

    config = Configurator(
        settings=settings,
        authentication_policy=authn_policy,
        authorization_policy=authz_policy,
    )

I have tried going through the documentation but I am unable to piece together the solution from it.

Did you find this topic? https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/whatsnew-2.0.html#upgrading-auth-20

I would agree, the documentation is very limited for applications that have heavily extended then older style approach. I have just started an upgrade on this, when I am finished I will send a pull request with some documentation examples.

Having now completed my migration I understand this a lot better, can you expand your question further to show how you are protecting your views and then this should allow us to guide you to a resolution.

There are two well published documents on this, the first being an extract on 2.0 release notes on how to upgrade. As well as a full example in the wiki2 application tutorial in the official documentation.
An updated example for the code you have provided would be:
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktCookieHelper
from pyramid.csrf import CookieCSRFStoragePolicy

class MySecurityPolicy:
    def __init__(self, secret):
        self.authtkt = AuthTktCookieHelper(
            secret,
            cookie_name='session-id',
            wild_domain=True, 
            hashalg="sha512")
        
def includeme(config):
    settings = config.get_settings()
    config.set_csrf_storage_policy(CookieCSRFStoragePolicy())
    config.set_default_csrf_options(require_csrf=True)
    config.set_security_policy(MySecurityPolicy('somesecret123'))


will set_security_policy be able to handle different methods which used to exist in the original AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy class?
For example authenticated_userid, forget, remember. Or I will need to re-implement them too?
I am asking this because I did not have any custom implementation for them. I was using the default behavior.

@smarakshailendra this is explained in "2.0 release notes" link I posted within this answer.
